# Prevent docker-containerd from listening on external interface port 10010

Tags: docker

I just recognized that `docker-containerd` is listening on my external interface on port `10010`:

```
$> ss ...
tcp LISTEN 0 128 x.x.x.x:10010 *:* users:(("docker-containe", ...
```

I can see the daemon uses a certain configuration file:

```
$> ps ...
docker-containerd --config /var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.toml
```

The problem is that I can find no configuration options in `containerd.toml` in order to change that behaviour.

Does anybody now how I could make `docker-containerd` listen on `127.0.0.1` instead on my external IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone ever comes across this issue again, you should just upgrade. It should be fixed in docker version 18.06.1 as said on [containerd's github](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/issues/2483).

Comment: yes yes indeed.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/#configuring-remote-access-with-systemd-unit-file

Here they talk about doing it two ways.

I tried both to no avail.  I can't even find a reference to the config your talking about either.

Comment: This is not what I was looking for.